# Measuring the bias-variance tradeoff

Tags: machine-learning, variance, cross-validation, bias, overfitting

Does anyone know of a metric that quantifies the bias-variance tradeoff of a given fitted model?

I'm not talking about measuring the MSE in cross validation, I'm interested in a single generic or model-specific metric (or statistical test) that measures the degree of bias and/or variance of a fitted model.

Comment: Knowing the bias would mean knowing the truth, in which case you would not need a model.  You can never measure the bias without knowing the truth.

Comment: This seems like a perfectly good, & clear, question to me. I'd be interested in reading some good answers, too. I'm voting to leave open.

Comment: @MatthewDrury considering that the answer talks about the MSE as well, I think the OP may have data on the truth, like in regression analysis. In many cases you may still want to model it for forecasting purposes

Answer (score 1):

$EEPSE = EE(\hat{f}(x_0)-y_0)^2$ is the average (or "expected", over different  predictions $\hat{f}(x_0)$ coming from different datasets) expected prediction squared error (for a particular $\hat{f}(x_0)$ over many test points $y_0$, at $x_0$)

To measure the bias-variance trade-off in a concrete example with concrete values, consider e.g. a population of 3 members: $0$, $0.5$, and $1$, each one occurring with the same probability. (The population is infinite). Now consider random `datasets that consist of one observation` from the population. There will be 3 types of datasets, which occur with the same (1/3) frequency. These datasets have observations "$0$", "$0.5$", and "$1$". Now `consider models of type: "The prediction for the next observation is equal to the average in the dataset times alpha"`. The average in the dataset is equal to the observation in the dataset, as we have just one observation in a dataset.

To measure the bias-variance tradeoff among different models (one model per "alpha"), plot the squared bias $[E(\hat{f}(x_0))-\mu_0]^2$, the variance $E(\hat{f}(x_0) - E(\hat{f}(x_0)))^2$, their sum, and their sum plus noise (which is the $EE(\hat{f}(x_0)-y_0)^2$). The "noise" is equal to $var(y_0)$.

What you will get is that the optimal alpha is $0.6$. Also, you will see that the unbiased model (alpha = $1$) can never be optimal, as the slope of the EEPSE is positive for alpha = $1$ (see the figure). This picture is true in general. There does not exist an unbiased model, which is optimal. The only two exceptions are: the dataset is infinite (and equal to the population), or the population consists of one member only. In these two corner cases (not practical) alpha=$1$ is optimal, as then $var(\hat{f}(x_0)) = 0$.

The *optimal alpha* is $$\frac{\mu_0^2}{\mu_0^2 + var(\hat{f}(x_0))} = \frac{0.5^2}{0.5^2 + var([0, 0.5, 1])} = 0.6, $$ which is always between $0$ and $1$, where $\hat{f}(x_0)$ is the prediction from the unbiased model "The prediction for the next observation is equal to the average in the dataset". The *optimal model* is:

> The prediction for the next observation is equal to the average in the dataset times 0.6

. This result may look "strange". It means that if we have one dataset, and it consists of (the single) observation "1", our prediction for the future observations should be 1 $\times$ alpha = 0.6; and if we have as observation "0.5", our prediction should be 0.5 $\times$ 0.6 = 0.3. Lastly, if we have as observation "0", our prediction should be 0 $\times$ 0.6 = 0. This model results in a smaller $EEPSE$ than the model "the prediction for the next observation is equal to the average in the dataset". Note that the "average in the population" results in the smallest $EEPSE$ (0.166667). So, we would like to predict "the average in the population". Alas, **the "average in the dataset" is not the best prediction for the "average in the population"**.

Multiplying an unbiased model by alpha in this case is called penalization. Note that the optimal alpha is in general unknow, as one needs to know the true $\mu_0$ in order to compute it. Still, the point to stress is that optimal alpha < $1$. Even if a small penalization is used (alpha very close to $1$), we will still have smaller test error than the unbiased model.

[image: Optimal choice of model]

Answer (score 0):

$E(y_0-\hat{f}(x_0))^2 = Var(\hat{f}(x_0)) + Bias(\hat{f}(x_0))^2 + Var(\epsilon)$

Where
 - $E(y_0-\hat{f}(x_0))^2$ is the expected test MSE.
 - $Var(\hat{f}(x_0))$ is variance of fitted model.
 - $Bias(\hat{f}(x_0))^2$ is squared biased of model.
 - $Var(\epsilon)$ is variance of error terms

Source: James, G., Witten, D., Hastie, T., & Tibshirani, R. (2013). An introduction to statistical learning (Vol. 112). New York: springer.

Comment: It was the same paragraph from the _Elements of statistical learning_ that made me ask this question. I was however asking about specialised metrics that would tell you specifically how to derive Bias(.) rather than assume it.